# Error al consumir web service con POST y GET en Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic, webservice, http, post

Hola tengo un problema que no me deja seguir adelante.
Tengo un Web Service  en la cual pide ingresar coordenadas (INPUT); estas, si son correctas, mandará en formato `JSON` un listado del nombre de las sucursales cercas (OUTPUT).

Se puede ver aquí:

http://saltala.cl/igniter/WSExamples/GetSucursales

El tema es que no he podido lograr enviar los parámetros para obtener esta informacion (`lat`, `long`) desde FrontEnd.

Datos:

- Input:

  `lat` (`float`): latitud del GPS

  `long` (`float`): longitud del GPS
- Output:

  Lista de empresas y sucursales con los siguientes parámetros: `id_sucursal`, `direccion`, `nombre_empresa`, `distancia`.

  Acceso: http://saltala.cl/igniter/Appmovil/GetSucursales

Código: Entiendo esto, se que esta mal y me gustaría si me pueden ayudar a corregir y completarlo por favor, e visto demasiados videos, he podido lograr conexion con un get, sin enviar parámetros, como en los cursos, pero de esto nada.

```js
function comotellames($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        url: 'http://saltala.cl/igniter/Appmovil/GetSucursales',
        method: "POST",
        data:
            latitud=  ???
            longitud= ??
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log(data)

        id_sucursal, direccion, nombre_empresa, distancia. ??

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(error),
        $scope.status = status; 
    });
```

Comment: La línea que está en el `success` debajo del `console.log` es un error de sintáxis. Es un comentario lo que debería ir ahí? También el parámetro `data` de la petición debe ser un objeto pero las llaves `{}` no aparecen por ninguna parte.

Comment: El objeto data del `$http` debería ser un objeto, es decir, `data: { latitud: 38.745515, longitud: -4.394531 }`

Answer (score 1):

Viendo la página que referencias me parece que el error está en como usas las promesas. Estás usando `success` y `error` que son métodos obsoletos. En su lugar escribe `then` y `catch`, también tienes algunos errores de sintáxis.

Tienes que usar `ng-model` en el `input` y después usar el `$scope` con su correspondiente binding para obtener el valor

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="lat">
```

se obtiene usando

```
$scope.lat
```

Debería quedar así

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('CoordenadasCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.enviar = function() {
      $http({
          url: 'http://saltala.cl/igniter/Appmovil/GetSucursales',
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            lat: $scope.lat,
            lng: $scope.lng
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('success');
          console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log('error');
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CoordenadasCtrl" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Latitud</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="lat">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Longitud</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="lng">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" ng-click="enviar()" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Nota: El snippet no funciona porque da acceso denegado. El código debe funcionar bien en tu servidor ya que este no hace CORS.

Comment: Muchas gacias estimado, me ha sido de gran ayuda, me ha aclarado grades dudas como lo succes, por otro lado lo ejecute y al mandar el input con las coordenadas me retorna un Object {success: "false"} en vez de los datos en formato JSON, ejemplo: {"success":"true","data":[{"id_sucursal":"19","direccion":"Av. Concha Y Toro 3459, Puente Alto","nombre_empresa":"Hospital S\u00f3tero","distancia":"16.387569","activo":"1"}]} y le vuelvo a dar las gracias, que tenga un buen día.

Comment: Edité el ejemplo para que puedas determinar cual de las dos vías esta sucediendo. Recuerda que el web service podría estarte devolviendo los datos correctos pero aun así indicándote que hay un error. El código de http para los errores son los `400-500`(`catch`) y los `200` es satisfactorio(`then`). Que tengas resultados significa que la petición está funcionando como se espera. No te olvides de votar la pregunta si te fue de utilidad.

Comment: @HernanHumaña La propiedad `status` te dice cual es el código del resultado de la petición. Si dice `200 OK` y dice `{success: false}` tiene que ver con tu server. Me fije que lo que envía la página de ejemplo es `lat` y `lng` y tu estas enviando `latitude` y `longitude`. Eso no es lo que espera el servidor y puede ser la causa del error. Corregí mi ejemplo.

Comment: @HernanHumaña Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

El campo `data` debe ser un objeto.
No tiene la sintáxis correcta, debería ser algo comó:

```
data:
   {
     longitud:'xxx',
     Latitud:'xxxx'
   }
```

Y ya debería funcionar, además la línea que esta después del console no parece tener sentido.

Saludos.